# Calling items from lists within a function in python 3

Tags: python, list, algorithm, function

I am trying to create a function to call items from 2 lists that are outside the function but I am stumped and not sure where to go or how to do it. The question is: write an algorithm that will call a function to determine the formula weight of chlorides formed from each of the following elements ["H", "Li", "Na", "K"] with respective weights [1.01, 6.94, 22.99, 39.10].
So far I have coded this:

```
elementsList = ["H", "Li", "Na", "K"]

weightsList = [1.01, 6.94, 22.99, 39.10]

chlorine = "Cl"

weight = 35.45

def formulaWeight ():

   element = elements[]
```

Please help on how to do this, I am truly stumped

Comment: For those of us whose chemistry knowledge is limited, can you give some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: What is `elements`, is that supposed to be `elementsList`?

Comment: yes sorry, I was editing and didnt catch that

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over each element and its associated weight using `zip()`, then add it to the chlorine weight:

```
elementsList = ["H", "Li", "Na", "K"]

weightsList = [1.01, 6.94, 22.99, 39.10]

chlorine = "Cl"

chlorineWeight = 35.45

def formulaWeight():
    for element, weight in zip(elementsList, weightsList):
        chlorideWeight = weight + chlorineWeight
        print(f"{element}{chlorine} has weight {chlorideWeight}")
```

Comment: Oh okay! that makes sense! Thank you